# SBT: Get dependendOn projects as jars

Tags: sbt

I have project declaration like this

lazy val myProject = (Project("name", file("path"))
    dependsOn(project1, project2))

is there any way to get project1 and project2 as jar files and get them as path? I need them to to copy in file system when compile myProject

I found projectDependencies contains all of them as ModuleID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(package in Compile in project1).value
```

And similarly for project2.